# At what event Java Agent premain method will be called?

Tags: java, javaagents

I'm getting bit confused on "class loading" concept along with javaagent.

Lets say I have an agent class like this:

```
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class Agent {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader classLoader, String s, Class<?> aClass, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] bytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

                // ASM Code for changing the bytecodes
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and I create an agent jar by setting up the `Premain-Class` to the `Agent` class.

Now I'm passing this agent jar while my VM start up using `-javaagent`, so the question is:

1. At what times the `premain` will be getting called? Only when class loaded by the classloaders? If so then this `premain` is called exactly once for each class is in `bootstrap`,`extension`,`system` loaders?
2. Or when ever I create a object of a class and then call its methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `premain` method of an agent will be called [once](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

> After the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) has initialized, each premain
>   method will be called in the order the agents were specified, then the
>   real application main method will be called. Each premain method must
>   return in order for the startup sequence to proceed.

Comment: oh ok. So basically then `addTransformer` of `Instrumentation` will be getting called for each class loading occurs correct?

Comment: @Ant's `addTransformer` will also be called once given your code. But the `transform` method of the transformer will be called for each loaded class, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#addTransformer%28java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer,%20boolean%29

Comment: Thank, now it make sense